# Image Flickering everytime table is reloaded (iOS, objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, caching

I am having an issue where my images in my tableview cell flicker everytime the table reloadData method is called.  The flickering is occuring because the image is being downloaded EVERY time the table is reloaded.  How do I make it so this image isnt being downloaded everytime, but only once?

This is the cellForRowAtIndexPath code in SelectStationViewController.m.  This class handles the tableView.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    StationRest * StationRest = [[CurrentUser sharedInstance].userStations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    StationListCell *cell= [[StationListCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 375,88)];
    cell.cellDelegate = self;

    //This method below downloads the image into the cell.
    [cell configureCellWithStationRest:StationRest forCellType:StationListCellTypeSelect];

    return cell;
}
```

This is the code in StationListCell.m, the class that is hooked up with the cell.  Here is where the image is downloaded using AFNetworking.  I can use GCD with [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL method instead of AFNetworking, but I still achieve the same result.

```
-(void)configureCellWithStationRest:(StationRest *)stationRest forCellType:(StationListCellType) cellType{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stationRest.thumbURL];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];

    [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [self.thumbButton setImage:responseObject forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.thumbButton setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
        } 
        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            DLog(@"Image error: %@", error);
        }];

    [requestOperation start];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UIImageView+AFNetworking.h category.It provides method to download the image from url and cache it.Please check its documentation for more information.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]];
[request addValue:@"image/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[yourImageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
    yourImageView.image = image;
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to load image");
}];
```

Comment: This didnt work.  I am using a button, not an imageview.

Comment: Nevermind.  I made the button transparent and put this under.. This works.  Thank you

Comment: Welcome @JoshO'Connor :)